# webview html rendering issue, image is getting cropped

Tags: android, html, css, web, android-webview

I am trying to render an image as html in webview of android but not able to calibrate it correctly in mobile, original image gets cropped both left and right using below code. how should I fix this and how to know if it will render fine on mobile (by running in browser only) ? below is what I am doing.

image dimensions are:(624*936)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+JP&display=swap"
    />
  </head>
  <body style="margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%">
    <div
      onclick="surface.touch()"
      style="
        background: url(https://image/startBackground_1)
          center center fixed;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 100%;
        background-size: cover;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        flex-direction: column;
        font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
      "
    >
      <div
        style="margin-bottom: 100%; margin-top: 100%;"
      ></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have background-size set to cover which means the image will get cropped either at the sides or top and bottom depending on its aspect ratio in relation to the viewport aspect ratio. Is that the problem  you describe? Using contain instead of cover will show all the image but there will be gaps at the sides or top/bottom depending on aspect ratios.